# Why does she self-immolate in Saint Maud

Tags: plot-explanation, saint-maud

In the movie Saint Maud, Maud pours Acetone all over her body and self-immolates.

But the whole movie establishes she is a devoted Roman Catholic Christian, and Christianity forbids people from committing suicide.

How does her self-immolation align with her devotion to Christianity?

Comment: It doesn't but then psychotics and fanatics often have a *warped* interpretation of what is  allowable even in the name of their supposed religion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Rose Glass**, the writer/director explains](https://mashable.com/article/saint-maud-ending-explained-hidden-details/):

> "In my head, it was a sudden snapback to a very harsh reality. **You see things on the news about people blowing themselves up or setting themselves on fire in the name of God, and it just always seemed so kind of alien to me. So I wanted to make up a story that traced that moment back to a relatable genesis** [and, in turn, carried it forward to a realistic conclusion.]"
>
> [...]
>
> "If you did interpret this as Maud misinterpreting God throughout the whole film, then she's just murdered somebody and it makes sense that she'd go to hell," Glass says. "Whatever is going on between her and God, yes, maybe there is something spiritual there. But **I think by that point something that maybe started off as faith has now mutated into quite a dangerous sort of delusion.**"